# How to unlock an input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable, html5-draggable

I need to have the move(draggable) property of the elements. But when I use the property(draggable) on input(text), I lose the ability to scroll the text in the intuition. Whenever I need to scroll through the text it move element.

```css
.list input{
  display: block;
  width: 60px
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <input type="text" draggable='true' value='text1 text2 text3 text4 text5'>
  <input type="text" draggable='true' value='text1 text2 text3 text4 text5'>
  <input type="text" draggable='true' value='text1 text2 text3 text4 text5'>
</div>
```

[image: img]

Help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to have it both draggable and scrollable (with the arrow).

What you'll want to do is either:
- Make the input wide enough you'll never need to scroll
- Wrap it up with something and make that draggable instead

A lot of UIs that allow for dragging around and ordering things will have a "handle" element which is where you grab it to drag, and that wraps up it's contents. That may not work with the `draggable` property all by itself, but you can use `mousedown` and `mouseup` events on the handle to toggle `draggable` on and off.